# authenticate user stored in freeradius by other system

Tags: radius, freeradius

need your assistance, im trying to authenticate a user stored in my freeradius+mysql in pfsense (acts as captive portal for wifi users)

```
AP+-----+PFsense+-----+Internet
            +
            |
            +
        FreeRadius
```

im pretty sure that my shared secret/ip of my radius is correctly defined in pfsense system. but im not quite sure if my radius allows authentication coming from other systems.

in /etc/raddb/clients.conf

i defined my pfsense as my NAS

```
     client 192.168.1.1 {
          secret = testing123
          shortname = pfsense
     }
```

selinux is already disabled.

maybe theres a parameter i needed to change or allow,
can you think what else i missed here? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the server in debugging mode (-X) it will complain if it receives a packet from an unknown client and tell you definitively which IP is being used as the SRC address.

You can then add a client entry with that IP.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the following links, as they describe the process of using captive portal along with local FreeRADIUS.

[https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/FreeRADIUS_2.x_package#HOW-TO_-*FreeRADIUS*.2B_Captive_Portal_configuration](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/FreeRADIUS_2.x_package#HOW-TO_-_FreeRADIUS_.2B_Captive_Portal_configuration)

http://pheriko.blogspot.mx/2013/01/pfsense-2-captive-portalfreeradius2.html

After successfully implementing the process you can find local clients.conf in order to rectify your client configuration.

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers. The link may become invalid.

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs I'll edit my answer and add the needed information from links